# Is it possible in ROS2 to concurrently RW a bag file?

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible in ROS2 to concurrently write-to and read-from the same bag file using two different processes, kind of  like using the bag file as a pipe? To my knowledge, this is not possible in ROS1, but I am curious if this is possible in ROS2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394797/is-it-possible-in-ros2-to-concurrently-rw-a-bag-file?/) by [ajayvohra2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/91833/ajayvohra2005/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2022-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried this and at least with the built-in storage plugin `sqlite3`, it is not possible. If one tries to open a `ros2` bag that is already open, one gets the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1642869934.723092322] [rosbag2_storage]: Could not open '/tmp/a.bag' with 'sqlite3'. Error: Failed to setup storage. Error: Could not read-only open database. SQLite error (10): disk I/O error
[ERROR] [1642869934.723146073] [rosbag2_storage]: Could not load/open plugin with storage id 'sqlite3'.
```

---

Originally posted by [ajayvohra2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/91833/ajayvohra2005/) with karma: 32 on 2022-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0